# Auto redirection after login except on WooCommerce checkout page

Tags: php, wordpress, redirect, woocommerce, checkout

I have a problem with WooCommerce. As default WooCommerce redirects users to My Account page after login.

I have set up a custom URL for users to be redirected after login by using this code:

```php
// Woocommerce redirect to panel klienta after woocommerce redirect
add_filter('woocommerce_login_redirect', 'wc_login_redirect');
 
function wc_login_redirect( $redirect_to ) {
     $redirect_to = 'https://example.com';
     return $redirect_to;
}
```

---

This works but the problem is that WooCommerce also auto redirects users when they log in on the checkout page.

This is bad because they've just added a product and want to pay for it.

How do I keep my custom redirect URL after login for users except for the checkout page where they should just login, not be redirected anywhere and just finish their order?

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

[wc_get_checkout_url()](https://woocommerce.wp-a2z.org/oik_api/wc_get_checkout_url/) – Gets the url to the checkout page

Then you can compare it with `$redirect_to`, and if it is equal, return the url of `$redirect_to` instead of the modified url

So you get:

```php
function filter_woocommerce_login_redirect( $redirect_to ) {    
    // Gets the url to the checkout page
    if ( $redirect_to == wc_get_checkout_url() ) return $redirect_to;

    // My url
    $redirect_to = home_url( '/myurl/' );
    
    return $redirect_to;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_login_redirect', 'filter_woocommerce_login_redirect', 10, 1 );
```